# Rolling up data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to rollup all the data from the base query into 2 columns avoiding the nulls.

Column 1 showing the filenumber and the next column showing either 1, 2....12 to show what no of join the filenumber came from as each join represent the number of link.

Please help. Query is below.

```
with base as
(select FileNumber as 1
       ,p3.FileNumber as 2
       ,p4.FileNumber as 3
       ,p5.FileNumber as 4
       ,p6.FileNumber as 5
       ,p7.FileNumber as 6

from pricing_advances p1 
left outer join pricing_advances p2  on coalesce([To File Number],reinstatedTo) = FileNumber 
left outer join pricing_advances p3 on coalesce([To File Number],reinstatedTo) = p3.FileNumber 
left outer join pricing_advances p4 on coalesce(p3.[To File Number],p3.reinstatedTo) = p4.FileNumber 
left outer join pricing_advances p5 on coalesce(p4.[To File Number],p4.reinstatedTo) = p5.FileNumber 
left outer join pricing_advances p6 on coalesce(p5.[To File Number],p5.reinstatedTo) = p6.FileNumber )
select * from base
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using (which I suspect is SQL Server).  Also, sample data and desired results would clarify what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very poor data structure.  Instead of storing values in columns, you should store them in a separate table, with one row per FileNumber.

Assuming the `FROM` clause is correct, you can get the first match using `COALESCE()`:

```
select COALESCE(p1.FileNumber, p2.FileNumber, p3.FileNumber, . . .
               ) as FileNumber
```

If you want a list of matches, then use string concatenation instead.  Assuming that `FileNumber` is a string:

```
select stuff( (coalesce(',' + p1.FileNumber, '') +
               coalesce(',' + p2.FileNumber, '') +
               coalesce(',' + p3.FileNumber, '')
               . . .
              ), 1, 1, '')
```